Персонаж — это тоже мем?
Персонаж — это лицо (персона) с характерными признаками, термин используется в литературе. Но в реальной жизни слово тоже встречается, например:
 Диалог
 — Вы же знаете, что она за персонаж... 
 — Сами вы персонажи!

А что такое мем? Хотя слово появилось недавно (Р. Докинз, 1976 год), существует уже направление в лингвистике, изучающее это явление. Да и в Сети много об этом пишут. Докинз образовал термин «мем» от греческого слова «мимем», что означает «подражание».
Это смысловое содержание  представляется мне важным, ведь многое в нашей жизни основано на подражании. Мем как единица культурной информации может иметь разное значение, в том числе негативное.
"По сути, мемы — это фольклор, цифровое народное творчество. Они отражают культурные особенности общества. Раньше из уст в уста передавались пословицы, поговорки и прибаутки, а сейчас передаются мемы".
Первым широко известным интернет-мемом считается «Танцующий ребенок». https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlG9yYW6Bi8  Ролик
Вопросы: (1) Можно ли персонаж (литературный или реальный) назвать мемом? (2) Когда эта характеристика приобретает негативный смысл, например: мемичные души, мемичное общество?
Статья по теме

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Мемом может стать всё, в том числе и литературный персонаж. Но прежде чем стать мемом, он должен адаптироваться под определенную ситуацию и распространится в интернете, т.е. стать вирусным.
А интерьере гуляют много литературных мемов. Поищите, найдете.

@Серж У нас уже вся литература превратилась в мемы, да  и писатели тоже. Вот Лермонтов вопрошает: Ну что, потомки, как вы там?  Стишок вот написала:  "Мой дядя самых честных правил,
Полтинник стукнуло ему –
Он приглашенья всем направил,
Тащусь и я сейчас к нему".  Это мем или нет?

А почему бы и нет? Возможно!

@Серж А самого Онегина можно назвать мемом, если  с его участием можно придумать бесконечно  большое количество мемов-сюжетов?

Конечно можно! Почему бы и нет?!

@Серж А Буратино считает, что нет.  Персонаж  – это не мем. И тогда возникает вопрос об определении слова мем,  а это, как мне думается, не так просто решить. Так что такое мем?

Мем - это идея, символ или образ, которые быстро распространяются от человека к человеку, а также в интернете. литературные мемы  — это герои и сюжетные ходы его произведений, а также факты биографии писателя отражаются в так называемых мемах – графических изображениях, содержащих в себе прецедентный текст или изображение, активно воспроизводящиеся в сети, в том числе в новых контекстах или ситуациях, отличных от оригинала.

@Серж  Спасибо.  Значит,  литературный мем – это уже особый случай.  А известные люди могут считаться мемом?  Вот Ди Каприо, например:  Поднимаю бокал за тех, кто ставит точку в конце предложения))  (И другие мемы с этой картинкой.)  Или только само конкретное изображение – это мем?

Я думаю, в данном случае именно конкретное изображение.

Спасибо! Значит, люди – это пока еще не мемы))  Хотя  нейросеть может и сюда внести поправку)

Все возможно в цифровом веке.

@Sharon "Люди – это пока еще не мемы" - есть те, кто к этому очень стремятся, это называется ловить хайп, ну и вообще популярность, идол-айдол, звезда - это из разряда мемов и с ними связанное. То есть люди, которые ЛЮДИ, пока они в тренде, пока о них говорят, как только они пропадают из инфополя - они уже не люди. Например Иисус - не мем, а Иисус Христос Супер Звезда - мем, древний правда.

@Серж Мем - это идея, символ или образ - не соглашусь, хотя мем конечно связан с логикой, но это не идея и не образ, это имидж - возможно, картинка; быть "в образе"? - хотя это больше относится к классическому театру, а не к мемам. Идея возвышает, а мем наоборот превращает в штамп, популяризирует тему как штамп. Мем связан с популяризацией идеологического продукта, когда "идея" завирусилась, а не со смыслом идеи, идеей как таковой.

Я придумал афоризм: есть люди, которые становятся персонажами, есть персонажи, которые становится людьми.

@Буратино Возможно) Но мне пришла в голову такая мысль: а может быть, мы все по большому счету являемся персонажами для Тех, кто выше нас и кто смотрит шоу под названием"Человеческая комедия"? Творец, вероятно, в каждого человека вкладывал какую-либо идею, поэтому мы все индивидуальны. В тоже время  нас можно разделить на какие-то группы и т. д. Вы какую-нибудь  идею можете к себе отнести или это не для вас?

@Sharon ну это и есть постмодерн - мы все и все вокруг в мире является повторением уже созданного когда-то, но в разных вариациях. Творец, это не дед на облачке который что-то вкладывал, творец - это творческий дух в человеке, который может стать автором созданного - создать что-то принципиально новое. А постмодерн отрицает автора-творца как такового. То есть раньше был, а теперь нет, нету. Есть только копии и ассоциации. Отсюда педивикии написанные без автора и интернет весь. Это уже не идеи - а просто информация, которую можно пилить и резать на цитаты и компилировать как вздумается.

Чат бот почему дурак, потому что у него нет мысли и связности повествования, весь его нарратив разбит на куски несвязанные друг с другом и нет мысли сквозящей, идеи нет. А идеи - это одна из основ философии, также как и логика, только логику придумал Аристотель, а идеи Платон, учитель Аристотеля. А насчёт индивидуальности.. само слово индивидуум более позднее, но оно дословно переводится как "представитель вида", то есть относящийся к некому общему. И индивидуальность - это отличие, но в рамках вида. Субкультура - это подвид культуры. Индивидуальность - не что-то уникальное, а что-то типичное

Но отличающееся, характерное для данной группы. Человек постмодерна типизируется по субкультуре которая является частью его индивидуальности - зумер, бумер, го, эмо, Спарта, Динамо.. - это индивидуальность. Ты не можешь сказать - я не болею за "футбол", тебе нужно выбрать группу - это называется "свобода". Без группы система не может тебя идентифицировать . Индивидуальность - это индификационный номер - индивидуальный код, позволяющей системе отличить тебя как типичную единицу.

Могу ли я отнести идею к себе? Поподробнее, не понял вопрос.
